# How to make specific color in pyplot using K-Means

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, k-means, numpy-ndarray

I have a dataset to need to make a K-Means figure using machine learning.

The following is my code

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets


df = pd.read_csv('../6_to_12_Month_All_Data.csv' ,encoding='utf-8')

X = df[['Yellow', 'Blue']].values
X

KM=KMeans(n_clusters=3,init='random',random_state=5)
KM.fit(X)
KM.predict(X)
plt.figure(figsize=(25,6))
plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1],c=KM.predict(X))
```

The following is the preset color, but I don't know know what to make the specific color.
[image: Result]

I want to make the above picture to yellow, blue and black, but I don't know what to fix it.

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

K-Means doesn't have much to do with this, it's a matter of scatter. It uses colormaps to decide which colors to use for the dots. You can pick any of the pre-made color maps from here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html

But if in your case you have specific colors you want to get, you can create your own color map like this:

```
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
cmap = ListedColormap([
    [1, 1, 0],  # Yellow
    [0, 0, 0],  # Black
    [0, 0, 1]   # Blue
])
[...]
plt.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1],c=KM.predict(X), cmap=cmap)
```

Result using your code with random data (as I don't have your csv):

[image: Plot with random data]